# How to change background-color of input when selected

Tags: css

I can't change the background-color of the input **when an option is selected**. When it's not is transparent.

[this is when options appear in my input with transparent background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkDmC.png)

[when i choose an option from before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TDIG.png)

It looks like a cyan type of color.

```
  input {
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
  input:required:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  input::placeholder {
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  input:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
```

What I've been trying so far

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "selected" here.

Comment: I edited the post with clear images

Answer (score 0):

```
input:focus
{
background-color:yellow
}
```

Comment: input:focus doesn't work when something is selected